# How to get intellij to stop showing methods in the project structure view?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It seems with Nov 2021 version of Intellij, the editor has started showing methods in the project structure view.   If your cursor is on a method in the editor, the project structure will open up and jump to this method.

I would like to disable it and go back to the old style project structure that didn't show methods.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gear icon, Tree Appearance, Show Members -> Disable.

[image]

Comment: You're a gentleperson and a scholar!

Comment: Perfecto, you're the man

Comment: I was added a stupid hot key "shift+control+option+command+y" for this options to hide "show members", it was not so easy to do it, moth*** fu*** android studio !!